# Excluding files in Swift Packages

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift-package-manager

To exclude entire sections of a file, I can use macros to target platforms such as `#if os(iOS) || os(watchOS)`.

Is there a way to do this in `Package.swift`, or another way to target a few files for specific platforms in Swift Package Manager?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in `Package.swift` ... ?

Swifty stuff *also works* in `Package.swift` since the package declaration file is itself a `.swift` file.

Here are some examples which use Swift 5.3 [Package Manager Conditional Target Dependencies SE-0273](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md) `condition` and `when`.

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

// ...
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "BKSecurity",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Crypto", condition: .when(platforms: [.linux])),
                "BKFoundation"
        ]),
```

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

// ...
    targets: [
      .target(
        name: "CombineShim",
        dependencies: [
          .product(name: "OpenCombine", 
                   package: "OpenCombine",
                   condition: .when(platforms: [.wasi, .linux])
        )]
      ),
      .target(
        name: "TokamakShim",
        dependencies: [
          .target(name: "TokamakDOM", condition: .when(platforms: [.wasi])),
          "SomeCommonDependency"
        ]
      ),
```

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let supportsCoreAudio: BuildSettingCondition = 
        .when(platforms: [.iOS, .macOS, .tvOS, .watchOS])
let supportsALSA: BuildSettingCondition = 
        .when(platforms: [.linux])

let package = Package(
    name: "portaudio",
// ...
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "libportaudio",
      dependencies: [],
      cSettings: [
        .define("PA_USE_COREAUDIO", supportsCoreAudio),
        .define("PA_USE_ALSA", supportsALSA)
      ],
      linkerSettings: [
        .linkedLibrary("asound", supportsALSA),
        .linkedFramework("CoreAudio", supportsCoreAudio),
        .linkedFramework("CoreServices", supportsCoreAudio),
        .linkedFramework("CoreFoundation", supportsCoreAudio),
        .linkedFramework("AudioUnit", supportsCoreAudio),
        .linkedFramework("AudioToolbox", supportsCoreAudio)
    ]),
  ]
//...
)
```

Note that `#if os(…)` can be used in `Package.swift`. However, ***`Package.swift` is evaluated, built and executed in the context of the build platform***. So, `#if os(…)` is useful in the context when *the target platform **is the same** as the build platform* e.g. macOS, Linux or Windows.

*Package.swift*

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    // ...
    targets: {
        var targets: [Target] = [
            .testTarget(
                name: "QuickTests",
                dependencies: [ "Quick", "Nimble" ],
                exclude: ["SomeFile.ext"]
            ),
        ]
#if os(macOS)
        // macOS build platform
        targets.append(contentsOf: [
            .target(name: "QuickSpecBase", dependencies: []),
            .target(name: "Quick", dependencies: [ "QuickSpecBase" ]),
        ])
#else
        // not macOS build platform, e.g. linux
        targets.append(contentsOf: [
            .target(name: "Quick", dependencies: []),
        ])
#endif
        return targets
    }(),
)
```

**See Also**

- [The Swift Programming Language: Statements > Conditional Compilation Block](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID538)
- [GitHub/Apple/swift: lib/Basic/LangOptions.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Basic/LangOptions.cpp)

  - Currently supported compilation OSs: `macOS`, `tvOS`, `watchOS`, `iOS`, `Linux`, `FreeBSD`,`OpenBSD`, `Windows`, `Android`, `PS4`, `Cygwin`, `Haiku`, `WASI`
- [GitHub/Apple/swift-evolution: SE-0273 Package Manager Conditional Target Dependencies](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md)

Comment: I tried the above but it seems it always tries to compile as macOS..

Comment: The exclude list can be directories, like "QuickTests"

Comment: I find this works for macOS vs. Linux, but when I try it with iOS, it seems to also include all the macOS stuff.

Comment: I'm not entirely positive at the moment, but I suspect that `#if os(macOS)` in `Package.swift` may be referring to the os on which Xcode is running and not on the target os that it is compiling for. But I'm not certain on that point.

Comment: @StevenW.Klassen ... good observation. And so it is: `Package.swift` is evaluated, built and executed in the context of the build platform. So, `#if os(…)` would only apply to the context where the target platform is the build platform. Updated answer has been posted with SwiftPM 5.3 `condition` examples.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Getting ` missing argument for parameter 'package'`